# using sidebar in v8 vs Rhino // not working vs working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, shared-libraries, v8

Having an issue with the sidebar not working when running in V8 but working well in Rhino. Reported to issue tracker but they can't reproduce the problem... and mention it might be an authentication problem. Hope someone can't help me figuring it out.

I'm running with two files one MASTER with all the code and html files, and the other as the working document that is referring to the library in the MASTER document.

In the Master code having the html opening code:

```
function projektkortNotesSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ProjektKort_html').setTitle('ProjektKort input').setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}
```

In the Master code the function to run when hitting Send in the sidebar:

```
function insertNoter(dato,venue,accomodation,contract,economy,reference,pr,notes){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sProjektKort = ss.getSheetByName('ProjektKort_New');
  var idag = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "yyyyMMdd");
  var datoTitle = "";

if(dato !== ""){
  //Indsæt Datonoter
    var datoNoterRange = sProjektKort.getRange("D2");
    var datoNoterValueOld = datoNoterRange.getValue();
    var datoNoterValueNew = idag+"\n"+dato+"\n\n"+datoNoterValueOld;
    datoNoterRange.setValue(datoNoterValueNew);
    var datoTitle = "Datonoter: ";
}

}
```

And the menu to open the sidebar also in the Master code:

```
function onOpen(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Sidebar')
        .addItem('Insert notes', 'projektkortNotesSidebar')        
        .addToUi();
}
```

The HTML file in the Master:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
<!-- The CSS package above applies Google styling to buttons and other elements. -->
<style>
<!-- put your CSS in here-->
.width-100 {
  width: 100%;
}
.width-50 {
  width: 50%;
}
</style>    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <H1>INDTAST NYE NOTER</H1>
  </head>
  <body>
  <!-- Create a input field to except a value form user, in this case there name -->
<p></p>
<p></p>
<div>
  <label for="text-title">Dato noter:</label>
</div>

<div>  
  <textarea cols="35" type="text-area" name="dato" rows="3" id="dato" ></textarea>
</div>
<p></p>


<div>
  <button class="blue" onclick='sendName()'>Indsæt Noter</button>
</div>
<p></p>
     
<div>
  <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  function sendName(){
   //Get the value of the input field
   var dato = document.getElementById("dato").value
   
   
   google.script.run.insertNoter(dato);
   $('#dato').val("");
  }
</script>
<p></p>

</body>
</html>
```

In the working file the script looks like this, where `IssueTracker` is the library name:

```
function onOpen(){
  IssueTracker.onOpen();
}

function insertNoter(dato){
  IssueTracker.insertNoter(dato);
}


function projektkortNotesSidebar() {
  IssueTracker.projektkortNotesSidebar();
}
```

When running:
Rhino // IssueTracker-167972301
Rhino // MASTER - IssueTracker-167972301
Working for both owner and users

Rhino // IssueTracker-167972301
V8 // MASTER - IssueTracker-167972301
Working for both owner and users

V8 // IssueTracker-167972301
V8 // MASTER - IssueTracker-167972301
Working for owner
NOT working for user

V8 // IssueTracker-167972301
Rhino // MASTER - IssueTracker-167972301
Working for owner
NOT working for user

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/167972301

[Link to Folder with the two files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1M6bYsroPBO60_IlnD7LQuEsEdGyhX6J7)

Comment: Are there any error message logged in the executions page or the web browse developer console? What operative system and web browser are you using? Have you already tried using Chrome in incognito mode with all the extensions disabled and signing in on a single account?

Comment: @Rubén It seems like the function is never called from the sidebar - and I'm getting no errores. I'm using OSX, chrome and I've tried in incognito. Still when it's the user there's a problem but the owner works perfectly.

Comment: I've tried now to run the same code directly without the library. This works both as the owner and user. So it seems it's something related to the use of library.

Comment: Can you provide more details on how you deploy the library, and what are the sharing settings of both spreadsheets and scripts? Is the user for whom it is not working a domain user or external? Did you implement logs in both your server-side and client-side for troubleshooting? If you bind your Apps Script to an standard GCP projects, you will be able to see logs even if it is another user who calls a function. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#viewing_stackdriver_logs_and_error_reports_in_the_google_cloud_platform_console

Comment: @ziganotschka Both spreadsheets are in the same folder and shared with editor access with the user. The user is tested both as a domain user and an external user. In the GCP log says that the function isn't found.

Answer (score 1):

I think this has to do with scoping being different in the V8 engine. You can review the incompatibilities and differences in the "[Migrating scripts to the V8 runtime](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration)" article.

The problem is that you have two `insertNoter()` functions – one in your "MASTER" library and the other in the spreadsheet's local script. When running V8, the library's version is being called rather than the local script. **Rename the functions to clarify which should be called.**

HTML

```
...
google.script.run.insertNoter(dato);
...
```

Local Script

```
function insertNoter(dato){
  IssueTracker.insertNoterLibrary(dato);
}
```

Library

```
function insertNoterLibrary(*) { ... }
```

Comment: I've tried to change the function names as suggested. But still doesn't work for the user only the owner.

Comment: It seems the function is actually never called from the sidebar.

Comment: @KasperEgelund It is called. I copied the files you provided and ran this as per your instructions. How are you confirming that the function wasn't called?

Comment: I'm not sure how it's called in english. But from the script editor I open the execution window. I can see that the onOpen is executed and also the projektkortNotesSidebar. But the insertNoterLibrary or before insertNoter don't run when it's the user hitting the Send button.

Comment: @KasperEgelund Did you clear the filter "Ran as:me" in the top left of execution window?

Comment: @Diego Yes I did.

Comment: @KasperEgelund Sorry but I can't recreate that issue. When you click the button in the sidebar, you should see your web console update state from IDLE to BUSY and then back to IDLE. Make sure that the button is actually executing client-side script too (`console.log('button clicked')`?). Finally, I'd try removing all of the unnecessary stuff in your projects–the copied files, functions with same names but different signatures, etc. Just to help you isolate what could actually be happening.

Comment: Thanks. I've maybe found some of the problem. The Master file (library) - it seems I need the user to run the function from this file to authenticate it not only in the working file but also in the Master file. Can this be true? And if yes can this be done in some other way and where/how can I find more info on this?

Comment: @KasperEgelund I did not authorize the library script with either of my accounts, so I don't think that's the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your situation for domain-external users and found the following solution for it:

### Transfer the code of your library to an alone-standing script.

- It is not necessary for a library to be bound to a spreadsheet
- It is not possible to explicitly share a script that is bound to a spreadsheet
- Probably the latter is the source of the problem

So,

- transfer the contents of your library into an empty Apps Script, alone-standing Apps Script project
- Save the project
- Go on `File-> Share` to share it with the users whom you want to access the script
- Run the file script manually from the editor once to trigger authorization flow
- Save a new version
- Retrieve the `Script ID`
- Import the new library with the new Script ID into the working document and remove the old one

Now the library should work as intended in V8 for any user with whom you shared it.

Comment: Thank you! - and actually I'm glad that you at least could reproduce the problem. Unfortunately when trying to follow your solution I can still not make it work for the user if the spreadsheet is running v8. The 'stand alone' scriptfile can be both but the spreadsheet referring to the library/script doesn't work in v8.

Comment: Did you run the library code once manually to trigger authorization flow? And share the script explicitly with the user (maybe there is a problem with the user beings signed in with the wrong account/multiple accounts)? Try to share the script as "anyone can edit" to discard sign-in problems.

Comment: I now made it work IF I not only as the owner but also as the user run the library code manually first. But I can't make all the employees first open the script library and tell them how to run it manually. Can't this be done more smooth?

Comment: In my case it is not necessary for the users to run the library code manually, it is is enough if only I do it -as long as I share the script file with those users (as editors).

Comment: Can it be something in the domain settings? I've run through all the settings and can't find anything relevant but perhaps I'm just missing something. I can of course run everything in Rhino but the fact that everybody can make it work in V8 and I can't bothers my logic me... ;-)

Answer (score -1):

There is a problem with the HTML file, while solving this might not solve main issue, IHMO you should fix it.

`<html>` is intented to be the root of the document but the HTML file has several tags above it. To solve this problem put the following lines between the `<head></head>` tags

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
<!-- The CSS package above applies Google styling to buttons and other elements. -->
<style>
<!-- put your CSS in here-->
.width-100 {
  width: 100%;
}
.width-50 {
  width: 50%;
}
</style>
```

Also move `<H1>INDTAST NYE NOTER</H1>` from `<head></head>` to `<body></body>`

Resources

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body

Comment: Thank you for this input. New to coding means a lot to learn ;-) Having now changed it - but as expected didn't solve the overall problem.